# WebBrowser control not opens URLs in native browser window when IE11 is disabled/uninstalled

Tags: .net, winforms, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm using a Windows Form application developed in .NET Framework 2.0. I can't upgrade the framework as 2.0 is the requirement. The application is used to host URL in WebBrowser control of a web application developed in .NET 4.5.2 and working fine. The web application loads HTML content which also contains the Hyperlinks. Now I am facing a the scenario where the IE11 is not available or it's disabled/uninstalled. When the windows form application runs and it loads the HTML content through the website and I try to click one of the hyperlink instead of opening the link in any other available browser (Chrome, Edge) it does nothing. Can you please give me a workaround to handle this scenario? I want the URL should be opened in any other available browser window.

Thanks.

Comment: Get the URI of the link that was clicked and `Process.Start()` it to open up the default Browser.

Comment: You could also try to [Navigate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigate) it to `_self` (see the `Navigate(Uri, String, Byte[], String)` overload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first get the link href of the url when click the link, then use [`Process.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0) to launch Edge/Chrome to navigate to the link.

The sample code is like below, it launches Edge (msedge.exe) to open the links:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var linkElements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach (HtmlElement link in linkElements)
    {
        link.Click += (s, args) =>
        {
            int iStartPos = link.OuterHtml.IndexOf("window.open('") + ("window.open('").Length;
            int iEndPos = link.OuterHtml.IndexOf("')", iStartPos);
            String url = link.OuterHtml.Substring(iStartPos, iEndPos - iStartPos);
            Process.Start("msedge.exe", url);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yu Zhou for your reply. But this is not working because webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted only hits when navigation happens through an anchor. But in my case all the anchors are opened through javascript method window.open('url'). I can't get the link using web browser control in this case.

Comment: Where do you write the `window.open('url')` method? If it is inline the element like this `<input type="button" onclick="javascript: window.open('url')" />`, there might be some ways to get the url. If the `window.open('url')` method is in the `<script>` tag, I think there's no way to get the url.

Comment: Yes we are using it like `<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.open('ur')">Click</a>`. How can we get the url and use Process.Start()?

Comment: If so, you can first get the `OuterHtml` of the element, then try to intercept string to get the url. I updated my code sample, and you can check it. I test with html code like this `<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.open('https://www.bing.com/')">Click</a>`, you may need to change the sample code according to your situation.

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou, I think you didn't get my point. Actually `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` doesn't trigger when an anchor is clicked through javascript like here: `<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.open('https://www.bing.com/')">Click</a>`. If i could land into the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` on anchor click event then i can handle everything like you did in your post above. Please note, only `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` runs when we "navigate" through anchor like this `<a href="htttps:/www.google.com">Google</a>`. Hope you got me!

Comment: It's so strange. I can trigger `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` when I use `<a href="#" onclick="javascript: window.open('https://www.bing.com/')">Click</a>`. I tested the code, and it works on my side.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I've created the new sample application and it's capturing the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` but not in original code. Thanks YuZhou for your help. I'll check the issue in original application.

Comment: Hi @YuZhou, the application i run in the web browser control is a SPA developed in reactjs. The `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` never runs when a link is clicked inside the application. I have found this `https://builderbook.org/` link behaves similar as my app. Please load this link in your sample app and click on Login button it will load the page but will never trigger the document completed. This is the same issue with my app right now.